# Future Depending on another Future

Tags: scala

How I make one future dependenting on another future. Say I have futures like this:

```
def foo1 : Future[String] = ???
def foo2 : Future[String] = ???
def foo3 : Future[String] = ???
def foo4 : Future[String] = ???
```

I want foo4 dependenting on foo3 and foo2 , and foo3 and foo2 dependenting on foo1. How I write this in for comprehension?

Comment: What do you mean with _"dependenting on"_? What would be an sample input and an expected output? - Please read [How to create a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am meaning that foo4 is not executing before foo3 and foo2 future please.

Answer (score 1):

If you create four `Future`s the way you show, then all four `Future`s will execute at the same time:

```
def foo1 : Future[String] = f1()
def foo2 : Future[String] = f2()
def foo3 : Future[String] = f3()
def foo4 : Future[String] = f4()
```

If you want to make them execute serially, do this:

```
for {
  foo1 <- f1()
  foo2 <- f2()
  foo3 <- f3()
  foo4 <- f4()
} {
  // do something with the results
}
```

This will stop executing as soon as one of the `Future`s fails, unlike the first version while will run all four `Future`s to completion.